# Give relative path of library project in intellij idea 11.1

Tags: android, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I successfully added a library project to the main project in intellij and everything up to this is fine, and it's also running nicely. But my problem is that I have to update this project to a private repository (BitBucket). So the problem is that I cannot get this library module in another pc (because I don't know how to give a relative path for that).

Or is there any other way to deal with this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IDEA project uses relative paths to the modules. If it doesn't work, try to keep the library module under the project root.